# why timervec need to be set into mtvec in xv6?

Tags: riscv, xv6

In `start.c/timerinit()`, `timervec` be written into `mtvec`.
But I don't know why this is needed?
As before `timerinit()`, all interrupts & exceptions are already delegated to supervisor-mode via code:

```
  w_medeleg(0xffff);
  w_mideleg(0xffff);
  w_sie(r_sie() | SIE_SEIE | SIE_STIE | SIE_SSIE);
```

Base on my understanding handler in `mtvec` will not be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Reading this: [groups.riscv.org](https://groups.google.com/a/groups.riscv.org/g/sw-dev/c/-KQnN5EPHF4), I'm not sure all the interruptions are delegated.

> > > Traps never transition from a more-privileged mode to a less-privileged mode. For example, if M-mode has delegated illegal instruction exceptions to S-mode, and M-mode software later executes an illegal instruction, the trap is taken in M-mode, rather than being delegated to S-mode.
>
> > What's the rationale to support delegating M-mode interrupts in mideleg? Wouldn't it be a moot point delegating e.g., M-mode external interrupts to S mode, since if it's an M-mode interrupt, only M-mode can handle it? I do notice that the mideleg register is WARL, and **indeed Qemu always hard-wires the M-mode interrupt delegation bits in mideleg to 0. Would real hardware behave the same way?**
>
> Yeah, you’ve effectively answered your own question: implementations generally hard-wire those bits to 0, and so there is no support in practice for delegating those interrupts.

Reading more attentively `kernelvec.S`, `start.c` and `trap.c`, we can see that :

- Only Machine timer is set
- Machine timer handler generates a S interruption
- The `devintr()` do not handle Software timer interrupt (code `0x8000 0000 000 0005`, see `scause` definition, page 55 from [The RISC-V Instruction Set Manual](https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-privileged-v1.10.pdf))

I think that the OS wouldn't work if the `mtvec` was not called.

So `mtvec` is well called, but the instruction `w_mideleg(0xffff);` could be replaced by `w_mideleg(0xff0f);` with the same effect I think.